# Run-time error : 1004 (Copying to another sheet)

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I'm trying to create a VBA Macro that would search for a non-blank cell in "Sheet1" and if non-blank, it would paste the respective active cell column from "Sheet1" to the same column in "Sheet2".

Below is my code, but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, because the code is throwing me an error : 1004.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim StartPoint As Range

    Set StartPoint = ActiveCell
'Change to necessary amount of Rows & Columns
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(9, 5), Cells(1000, 200))
        Set cel = .Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1000, 200), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not cel Is Nothing Then
            strAddress = cel.Address
            Do
                ' Do something with cel, e.g.
                StartPoint.EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(StartPoint.Column & "1").End(xlToRight).Offset(1)
                Set cel = .FindNext(After:=cel)
                If cel Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Loop Until cel.Address = strAddress
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Can someone kindly advise what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: 1) Not searching here for *Run time error 1004*. 2) Not using the debugger to step through the code to see which of the times you're trying to access an object reference is failing or incorrect. 3) Not searching here again for *run time error 1004*.

Comment: Hi, I did run the debugger & it shows the error at the "with" statement. And I understand that the error was thrown because VBA didn't grasp which cells I was referring to within the range. But the problem is I'm not a power macro user & just a toddler still learning the basics haha! :) Appreciate if you can kindly let me know what mistake I'm doing in the code! :D

Comment: FWIW - the unqualified `Cells` references make the statement `With Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(9, 5), Cells(1000, 200))` equivalent to `With Sheets("Sheet1").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(9, 5), ActiveSheet.Cells(1000, 200))`, which is obviously nonsense. But you really wanted `With Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, 5), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1000, 200))`.  As @KenWhite said, a search on this site would have found hundreds of questions showing that to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these two modifications:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E9:GR1000")
```

.

```
cel.EntireColumn.Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(cel.Column)
```

Comment: Hello :) Thank you for your prompt response!
This removed the error, but the values don't get pasted to Sheet2.
I added destination:= to the
StartPoint.EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(StartPoint.Column)

but still the result is same. Is there another line that i need to add, in order to paste the copied columns from Sheet1 to Sheet2?

Comment: Ah, I think you need to substitute `StartPoint` with `cel` (see Edited answer). @DragonWarrior

Comment: Thank you again :) I understand the concept! I think I need to tweak this block abit more to suit my necessity. Nevertheless, thank you again :)